# Reading an email string from a cookie in java

Tags: java, javascript, email, struts2, cookies

My application needs to store the users email address in a cookie so that I can pre-populate a login form `(username == email address)`. I set the cookie value in JavaScript. If I read it from JavaScript, I get `foo@bar.com`. If I look at it in the cookie viewer in Firefox I get `foo@bar.com`.

When I try to read it on the server-side in Java however, I only get `foo`.

Do I need to do some sort of encoding/decoding here? If so, how do I do it in a way that can be decoded by both JavaScript and Java?

Thanks in advance!
-Michael

Answer (score 4):

From the [javax.servlet.http.Cookie](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setValue(java.lang.String)) doco for setValue(String):

> Assigns a new value to a cookie after
>   the cookie is created. If you use a
>   binary value, you may want to use
>   BASE64 encoding.
>
> With Version 0
>   cookies, values should not contain
>   white space, brackets, parentheses,
>   equals signs, commas, double quotes,
>   slashes, question marks, ***at signs***,
>   colons, and semicolons. Empty values
>   may not behave the same way on all
>   browsers.

I'm guessing you need to BASE64 encode it on the way in (via JavaScript) and on the way out (via Java)

Comment: Please see post below about equals sign... (what's with the 300 char limit on comments?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the value part of your cookie.

```
document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) 
    + ( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" )
    + ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) 
    + ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) 
    + ( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions to this. Here is the first one.

Add back in padding to Base64 encoded strings. Inspiration for this came from http://fi.am/entry/urlsafe-base64-encodingdecoding-in-two-lines/

In this solution, the JavaScript stays the same (base64 encode everything) and the server side looks like:

```
public class CookieDecoder {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CookieDecoder.class);

/**
 * @param cookieValue The value of the cookie to decode
 * @return Returns the decoded string
 */
public String decode(String cookieValue) {
    if (cookieValue == null || "".equals(cookieValue)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!cookieValue.endsWith("=")) {
        cookieValue = padString(cookieValue);
    }
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Decoding string: " + cookieValue);
    }
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    byte[] encodedBytes = cookieValue.getBytes();
    byte[] decodedBytes = base64.decode(encodedBytes);
    String result = new String(decodedBytes);
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Decoded string to: " + result);
    }
    return result;
}

private String padString(String value) {
    int mod = value.length() % 4;
    if (mod <= 0) {
        return value;
    }
    int numEqs = 4 - mod;
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Padding value with " + numEqs + " = signs");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numEqs; i++) {
        value += "=";
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

On the JavaScript side, you just need to make sure you base64 encode the values:

```
var encodedValue = this.base64.encode(value);
document.cookie = name + "=" + encodedValue + 
                  "; expires=" + this.expires.toGMTString() + 
                  "; path=" + this.path;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is just to URLEncode the Base64 encoded string. I'm using commons codec to do the encoding here. Java Code:

```
public class CookieDecoder {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CookieDecoder.class);

    /**
     * @param cookieValue The value of the cookie to decode
     * @return Returns the decoded string
     */
    public String decode(String cookieValue) {
        if (cookieValue == null || "".equals(cookieValue)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Decoding string: " + cookieValue);
        }
        URLCodec urlCodec = new URLCodec();
        String b64Str;
        try {
            b64Str = urlCodec.decode(cookieValue);
        }
        catch (DecoderException e) {
            log.error("Error decoding string: " + cookieValue);
            return null;
        }
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        byte[] encodedBytes = b64Str.getBytes();
        byte[] decodedBytes = base64.decode(encodedBytes);
        String result = new String(decodedBytes);
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Decoded string to: " + result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

But now I have to decode it on the JavaScript side as well...
Encode:

```
var encodedValue = this.base64.encode(value);
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(encodedValue) + 
                  "; expires=" + this.expires.toGMTString() + 
                  "; path=" + this.path;
```

Decode:

```
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
        c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
        var encodedValue = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        return this.base64.decode(unescape(encodedValue));
    }
}
return null;
```